# Non-static method referenced from a static method error message?

Tags: java, static

Writing a program to calculate simple interest and have to use separate methods to return the calculations and make the calculations.

```
public class Unit7B
{
   public static void main ( String [ ] args ) 
   {
       double p = Input.getDouble ("Enter the principal");
       double i = Input.getDouble ("Enter the interest rate");
       double n = Input.getDouble ("Enter the number of years");

       double result = simpleInterest( p, i, n); 
       System.out.println (result);
   }

   public double simpleInterest (double p, double i, double n)
   {
       return ( p * ( Math.pow ( 1.0 + i , n ) ));
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Java and the "simpeInterest (p, i , n);" is said to be non static method referenced in a static method

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark `simpleInterest` as a static method:

```
public static double simpleInterest (double p, double i, double n)
{
    return ( p * ( Math.pow ( 1.0 + i , n ) ));
}
```

This is because nonstatic methods require a class instance while static methods do not. In order to use your nonstatic method, you would have to create the class using something like this:

```
Unit7B unit = new Unit7B();
unit.simpleInterest(p, i, n);
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new a java, so where would I put that code block?

Comment: Which code block? You should just change the method to be static.

Comment: The Code you provided:  Unit7B unit = new Unit7B();
unit.simpleInterest(p, i, n);  should that be swapped with the main method name or the other method?